# I made Ubuntu Thrash My Win 8 MBR - Can I restore it and my data?

Tags: data-recovery, windows-8, mbr

I have a lovely Lenovo G780 that came with Win7 which I upgraded to Win 8 -

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10.Iso and the App that let me set up a boot USB stick.

I tried to run Ubuntu (For the first time) and it Showed me options where it said it couldnt See Windows 8 - (1TB drive split into 2)
I chose the LVA option thinking it would work out about my partition but it seems to have scrubbed everything

I stopped the install - so now I have a brick - The recovery button doesnt boot or recover, the Ubuntu Wont boot - Can I get back my windows 8 and the data I had n that partition

Comment: at what point in the install did you stop it?  What messages were on-screen at the time?

Answer (score 1):

Boot the Ubuntu LiveUSB and run the command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

to look at the drive and partitions.  If there are only two partitions on the hard drive - ext4 / and a swap partition then you have re-partitioned and formatted your hard drive.  Recovery would be difficult but you could try testdisk to see if will recognise any of the old partitions and the data on them.

If you have multiple partitions including your Windows hidden recovery partition and the NTFS Windows partition, then you could try to mount the main NTFS partition to copy your data off it.

Backups of important data are highly recommended before installing any operating system or doing anything to partitions.  Data recovery in cases where things go wrong can be a difficult and expensive process.  You should immediately image the drive to a backup device of sufficient size before you do very much to it - ie don't write any more data to the hard drive until you've recovered everything possible.